# Most efficient way to count how many rows have been entered in different tables within the X days?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery

Given several tables, what is the best way to take a poll of row counts in the tables with where clauses included? I'd like to do it at once so it can be inserted into a table with a daily record of row counts.

tableA - count of all rows that fit condition 1, a specific column value X
    select count(*) from tableA where col1 = X

tableA - count of all rows that fit condition 2, a specific column value Y
    select count(*) from tableA where col2 = Y

These two are easily combined into:

```
select
(select count(*) from tableA where col1 = X) as 'X count',
(select count(*) from tableA where col2 = Y) as 'Y count'
```

But now I'd like to add in:
tableB - count of all rows that were created within the last specified interval

```
select count(*) from tableB where dateCreated >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day) where col3 = Z;
```

This gives me:

```
select
(select count(*) from tableA where col1 = X) as 'X count',
(select count(*) from tableA where col2 = Y) as 'Y count',
(select count(*) from tableB where dateCreated >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)) as 'Z count';
```

It seems to run very slowly though, is there a more efficient way of counting rows in this case?

Comment: If the tables use the InnoDB engine then counting will be slow in general, since each row must be visited to determine if it is visible to the current transaction.  (And with a query like this, MyISAM will be slightly better since it will be able to visit only a matching index.)

Comment: Create indexes on `TableA(col1) and `TableB(dateCreated)` to speed up the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine, but you should index on those columns. To do so, from [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html):

```
CREATE INDEX idx_col1 ON tableA (col1);
CREATE INDEX idx_col2 ON tableA (col2);
CREATE INDEX idx_dateCreated on tableB (dateCreated);
```